# change compare function in assembly and .exe stopped working x64dbg

Tags: assembly, debugging, x64dbg

I'm trying to bypass (crack) a very old software that require license in order to unlock all the features

i was digging in the lines with a little bit of knowledge in assembly
and i found the line where it compare the hash of the request code with the hash of the license i entered

this is the line ( not %100 sure )
[image]

arrow1 where the random request code generated and the entered license saved to a param (not sure)

arrow2 where the compare happen ( same not sure)

The software compare a hash with the hash of the key code you entered, if it's the same, it will work

a random license request code generated everytime you run the .exe

using GenerateRandomNumber

[image]

and hashed by using HkdfHashAlgorithm

[image]

my question is

when i change `je 0x7C1AEF1F` to `jne 0x7C1AEF1F`

[image]

the software stopped working and when i execute it i got the command prompt for 1second and disappear

[image]

so what i need to change in order to compare the hash of the request code with the same hash or to say if not equal so activated...

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Algorithm**: ((Licence request code) + 0x26946948) ^ (your serial number of `C:` volume or `0xffffffff` if failed).

- This [keygen](https://play.golang.org/p/Wi2maUZ7ti_N) I'm written in golang.
- Or javascript keygen

  `function keygen(code, serial) {
   code = parseInt(/([0-9-]{12})/.exec(code)[0].replace(/-/g, ''))
   return ((code + 0x26946948) ^ parseInt(serial.replace(/-/g, ''), 16)) >>> 0
  }
  // example
  // '9950-7444-3132-b9' is Licence request code
  // 'A639-6EDE'         is Volume Serial Number of C:
  keygen('9950-7444-3132-b9', 'A639-6EDE')`

[image: serial]

- Or modify assembly at **file.exe+178A** `je file.exe+17B4` -> `jne file.exe+17B4` to bypass.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, please how can i use that keygen? and where i find SpoolManager.exe+17B4 ?

Comment: @JDEV, see my edit to usage javascript keygen :D

Comment: Man, i don't know how you did it, it's working, i really don't understand how you figure it out, please if you have time, explain it, i'm very interested / i spent more than 10 hours digging in assembly lines without success, for me your code looks like a magic, haha, Thank you very much i really appreciate it

Comment: How can i find SpoolManager.exe+17B4 in x64dbg please ?

Comment: I'm using Cheat Engine to debug this program, SpoolManager.exe+17B4 = 00400000 + 17B4 = 004017B4

Comment: You was able to find out that it work like that, that's really awsome, if it possible to send me a private video of the steps briefly, i'm very interested, i want to know how you searched and what's the keywords you used in cheat engine
Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59779927/javascript-function-to-java  i appreciate it for any help